# Related records in a published service

Tags: arcgis-flex-viewer

I have published a GIS service with a relation to a table view (in ArcMap I created a "relate" between the point shapefile and the table and the related records all show up here - then I did "share as service"). When I display it in the web map (viewer for flex) you are able to scroll through the correct number of related records, but no data is displayed for each - it says only "no related records".

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Would you be able to edit your question to provide precise details about how you "published a GIS service with a relation to a table view", please?